# Assign byte or int to List<int> or byte C#

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda, c#-3.0

```
 var x1 = this.db.VW_Validation_Quantity.Where(x => x.partition_id == partitionId).ToList();
```

above line returning 1167 records. all the records will contain the claim_validation_test_id, i want to add this id to `List<int> or List<byte>` so i uses anonymous  types with specific model created.

```
public class ValidationModel
{
 public List<byte?> claim_validation_test_id { get; set; }
}




List<ValidationModel> result1 = this.db.VW_Validation_Quantity.
Where(x => x.partition_id == partitionId)
.Select(y => new ValidationModel
 {
  claim_validation_test_id = new List<byte?>() { y.claim_validation_test_id },
 }).ToList();
```

both the lamda expressions will be same , only difference is am modifying  test_id byte type and assign to List. but second lamda expession returning 363 records.

first expression giving 1167 records.
second expression giving 363 records.

if i modify the second expression by normal byte assignment, then it is giving 1167 records. i.e.

```
List<ValidationModel> result1 = this.db.VW_Validation_Quantity.Where(x => x.partition_id == partitionId)
            .Select(y => new ValidationModel
        {
            testid =  y.claim_validation_test_id ,



        }).ToList();
```

I am not sure what is the reason why it differs for the same table.

Comment: `partitionId` in both case is the same, isn't it?

Comment: @valentin yes same

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by adding ToList() after where part. I am not sure how the issue was fixed but after adding ToList() after where part it is returning all 1167 records.

```
List<ValidationModel> result1 = this.db.VW_Validation_Quantity.
Where(x => x.partition_id == partitionId).ToList()
.Select(y => new ValidationModel
 {
  claim_validation_test_id = new List<byte?>() { y.claim_validation_test_id },
 });
```